# How to show custom taxonomy in tab not working when using with wp post query?

Tags: wordpress

I am new Wordpress and I want to use custom post type categories as based on pagination, Below is my code in which Tab's name is working fine but the content it does not show anything so as for pagination.

```
<?php
$currentPage = get_query_var('paged');
echo '<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">';
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'blogposts_categories',
    'hide_empty'=> 1,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$categories = get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo 
        '<li>
            <a href="#'.$category->slug.'" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">    
                '.$category->name.'
            </a>
        </li>';
}
echo '</ul>';

echo '<div class="tab-content">';
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<div class="tab-pane" id="' . $category->slug.'">';
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'freight_blogposts',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'paged' => $currentPage,
        'taxonomy' => 'blogposts_categories',
         'category_name' => $category->slug,


    ));

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<h1>';
        the_title();
    echo '</h1>';
    endwhile; 
} 
echo '</div>';
echo "<div class='page-nav-container'>" . paginate_links(array(
    'total' => $posts->max_num_pages,
    'prev_text' => __('<'),
    'next_text' => __('>')
)) . "</div>";
?>
```